# Why are these line bundles isomorphic? [modified]

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Reading a book I met the following claim, and I don't understand how to justify it. [Actually I misunderstood the claim, below is the corrected version of it]

Let $X$ be a variety and $E\subset X$ a divisor. Suppose we have a global section
$$ s: \mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_X(E) $$
such that the vanishing locus of $s$ is a divisor $D\subset X$, and that $s$ vanishes of order $1$ there. Under these assumptions, it follows that $L(D)$ and $L(E)$ are isomorphic.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my problem was I misunderstood the claim.

Now it's quite clear: the conclusion follows from the well-known fact that a section $s$ belongs to $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}(D))$ if and only if $(s) = D$, i.e. if and only if $s$ vanishes of order $1$ over $D$ (and nowhere else).